# Calculating ratio of values with specific labels in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements

I have a `data.table` and I need to add additional column that is a ratio between labels == 1 and labels == 2 for same cID. I have the code that can do that but the results is the reduced form according to the number of unique "l". But I need a full list with duplicates. Any suggestions? Thank's in advance!

```
x   y   l   cID
0.03588851  0.081635056 1   1
0.952514891 0.82677373  1   1
0.722920691 0.687278396 1   1
0.772207687 0.743329599 2   1
0.682710551 0.946685728 1   2
0.795816439 0.024320077 2   2
0.50788885  0.106910923 2   2
0.145871035 0.802771467 2   2
0.092942384 0.335054397 1   3
0.439765866 0.199329139 1   4
```

to reproduce

```
x = c(0.03588851,0.952514891,0.722920691,0.772207687,0.682710551,0.795816439,0.50788885,0.145871035,0.092942384,0.439765866)
y = c(0.081635056,0.82677373,0.687278396,0.743329599,0.946685728,0.024320077,0.106910923,0.802771467,0.335054397,0.199329139)
l = c(1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1)
cID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4)
dt <- data.table(x,y,l,cID)
dt[,sum(l == 1)/sum(l == 2), by = cID]
```

I need to obtain the ratio column that looks like this

```
x   y   l   cID ratio
0.03588851  0.081635056 1   1   3
0.952514891 0.82677373  1   1   3
0.722920691 0.687278396 1   1   3
0.772207687 0.743329599 2   1   3
0.682710551 0.946685728 1   2   0.333333333
0.795816439 0.024320077 2   2   0.333333333
0.50788885  0.106910923 2   2   0.333333333
0.145871035 0.802771467 2   2   0.333333333
0.092942384 0.335054397 1   3   Inf
0.439765866 0.199329139 1   4   Inf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close.  Try this:

```
dt[, ratio := sum(l == 1) / sum(l == 2), by = cID]
```

Comment: It does not make use of the data's order.  Its just a ratio of sums.

Comment: @JohnAmraph If you mean if the groups aren't together but jumbled up, will it still work? Yes. In that case you can think of each group being copied out to a contiguous chunk, the `sum` or order dependent `cumsum` for example ran on that, and then the result put back on the rows where the groups originally were. If that makes sense.